# Find the coordinates of the center of a circle with circles equations

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Let's say A(3;5) and B(-1;2) and Circle C with a diameter of [AB].
How can i find the coordinate of the center of the cricle ?
I tried to make it with circles equation like:

```
(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 = r^2
```

but i got

```
y^2-16x+y = 1
```

and so i don't know how to get the coordinates with that if this is right.

Comment: Where does the center of the circle lie in relation to a diameter?

Comment: it's in a Cartesian coordinate system

Comment: If what you’re ultimately trying to obtain is an equation of the circle, a simple one can be written down directly using the end coordinates of a diameter.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: Use the theorem that the inscribed angle of a diameter is a right angle and that the dot product of perpendicular vectors is zero.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you

Comment: What if you calculated the midpoint of $AB$ which would be $(1, 3.5).$ Wouldn't that be the centre of the circle for a diameter $AB$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you work your way through analytic geometry, don’t lose sight of the *geometry* part. Otherwise, you’ll find yourself floundering in a sea of algebra.

The midpoint of a diameter is the circle’s center. I expect that you know how to compute the midpoint of a line segment. I’m guessing that you’re looking for the coordinates of this point in order to plug it into the equation template $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$.

Note, though, that if you have the endpoints $A$ and $B$ of a diameter, you can write an equation of the circle down directly. The inscribed angle of a diameter is a right angle and the dot product of perpendicular vectors is equal to zero. Putting these two facts together we get the equation $$(x-x_a)(x-x_b)+(y-y_a)(y-y_b)=0$$ for the circle with diameter $AB$.

Answer (score 0):

Center of circle as you mentioned in comments is the midpoint of line $AB$ : $ (h=1, k=3.5). $ This should come at first.

Next the length of diameter $AB=\sqrt{3^2+4^2} =5 = 2 r $ and radius $r=2.5$

and lastly the circle has equation

$$ (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2 $$